# Save and Save As in Telerik RichText Editor

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik

I am using `Telerik RichTextBox Editor`(the one like MS Office) in my WPF project. When I save a file, and attempt to save it again later after making changes it opens up the `SaveFileDialog` and asks for the file name even though I've already defined it and saved it (like it thinks I'm using Save As, rather than Save). How can I solve this issue??

I am using

```
<telerik:RadRibbonButton telerik:RadRichTextBoxRibbonUI.RichTextCommand="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}" Size="Small"
         SmallImage="pack://application:,,,/Telerik.Windows.Controls.RichTextBoxUI;component/Images/MSOffice/16/save.png" Text="Save" />
```

Comment: What happens when you use `Save vs SaveAs`...?

Comment: the main problem is there is only one command provided by telerik, which is SaveCommand, which acts as SaveAs

Comment: I take it that http://www.telerik.com/ClientsFiles/369180_CustomSaveCommand.zip didn't give you the answer? i.e. save to the current file context or open the save file dialog

Comment: @PaulZahra : I tried to do the job using this one, but I think I still need a CustomOpenCommand too, to store the address of an opened file, so that I can save the changes to the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't got a solution yet from anyone. Working on it, have some progress using [CustomSaveCommand](http://telerik.com/ClientsFiles/369180_CustomSaveCommand.zip). Will post a complete solution when I get one.
If anyone gets one before I do, I'll accept it. Thanks all.

**Solution:**

Got a solution. Created a custom OpenCommand using the [CustomSaveCommand](http://telerik.com/ClientsFiles/369180_CustomSaveCommand.zip) and [radrichtextbox-Import/Export](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radrichtextbox-features-import-export.html). Hold in a `string variable`, the full path of the file on open/save a document, and overwrite the file on next save without the filedialog. Also reset the variable on new file open. Hope it helps anyone who is searching for a solution. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly setup a custom filebrowser provider and do what you want in there, i.e. see [custom filebrowsercontentprovider](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-custom-filebrowsercontentprovider.html). Besides a few other bits and bobs just inherit from Telerik.Web.UI.Widgets.FileBrowserContentProvider class.

Here is a nice example of using a sql database for the files: [sql database](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/file-explorer/connect-radfileexplorer-or-radeditor-to-a-sql-databse.aspx)